# Get opposite of a query's results Access 2016

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to create an query that displays the opposite of another query (just like a boolean NOT).
This is the first query:

```
SELECT RoomNumber, StructureNumber
FROM TimeTables
WHERE HourNumber = 1 AND  DayNumber = 1
```

I need to get all the rows that doesn't exists in that query's results.
At the first time I tried to subtract the full table from the first query but I could not do it because there is no "EXCEPT" in Access and 
also because I need to subtract between four columns (there are two primary key columns in that table)
this is my first try that didn't work:

```
SELECT RoomNumber, StructureNumber
FROM TimeTables
EXCEPT
SELECT RoomNumber, StructureNumber
FROM TimeTables
WHERE HourNumber = 1 AND  DayNumber = 1
```

At the second time I try to pull the result that dosn't exists in the first query but also didn't work:

```
SELECT RoomNumber, StructureNumber
FROM TimeTables
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
SELECT RoomNumber, StructureNumber
FROM TimeTables
WHERE HourNumber = 1 AND  DayNumber = 1)
```

I've searched for solutions at the internet and found some things that similar to my problem but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT RoomNumber, StructureNumber
FROM TimeTables
GROUP BY RoomNumber, StructureNumber
HAVING SUM(IIF(HourNumber = 1 AND  DayNumber = 1, 1, 0)) = 0;
```

The `HAVING` clause counts the number of rows (for each `RoomNumber`/`StructureNumber` combination) that match your specified conditions.  The `= 0` means that there are no such rows.

Comment: This query gives me the perfect results I wanted, thank you very much. but can you explain me please what is going on in this query? I don't know the ""IFF" function and don't understand the way you used "HAVING SUM" with it.

Answer (score 1):

`NOT EXISTS` requires reference from the `outer query` which you haven't supply

So, your `NOT EXISTS` should be :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TimeTables t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                  FROM TimeTables t1
                  WHERE t1.RoomNumber = t.RoomNumber and t1.StructureNumber = t.StructureNumber and 
                        t1.HourNumber = 1 AND  t1.DayNumber = 1
                  );
```

But, for instance `where` clause should enough

Answer (score 0):

Simply correlate the `NOT EXISTS` subquery to main query, facilitated using table aliases, *t* and *sub*:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TimeTables t
WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT 1
    FROM TimeTables sub
    WHERE sub.HourNumber = 1 AND sub.DayNumber = 1
      AND sub.RoomNumber = t.RoomNumber 
      AND sub.StructureNumber = t.StructureNumber)
```

But simply run a `WHERE` clause reversing the logic:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TimeTables t
WHERE t.HourNumber <> 1 OR t.DayNumber <> 1
```